# How to split list in sublists based on string length?

Tags: python

I have the following input list `data`

```
data = '''ABCD1
2040805025@HHS_2332
801111@PPOD_1
225@DDMDM
DEFA1
23333@HHS_998
7859000@FGL3
44532009@LLLKH_9
225@DDMDM
FGGH5
78271@WQE
8003013@UTTY7'''.split()
```

If I want to split in sublist of lenght 3 I can use this

```
In[1]: [data[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(data),3)]

Out[1]: 
[['ABCD1', '2040805025@HHS_2332', '801111@PPOD_1'],
 ['225@DDMDM', 'DEFA1', '23333@HHS_998'],
 ['7859000@FGL3', '44532009@LLLKH_9', '225@DDMDM'],
 ['FGGH5', '78271@WQE', '8003013@UTTY7']]
```

But how to split the list each time a string of 5 characters appears (in this example `ABCD1,DEFA1 and FGGH5`)? to get this output:

```
[
 ['2040805025@HHS_2332','801111@PPOD_1','225@DDMDM'],
 ['23333@HHS_998','7859000@FGL3','44532009@LLLKH_9','225@DDMDM'],
 ['78271@WQE','8003013@UTTY7']
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a listcomp to exclude the *5-character* strings :

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [list(g) for check, g in groupby(data, lambda s: len(s)!=5) if check]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

[['2040805025@HHS_2332', '801111@PPOD_1', '225@DDMDM'],
 ['23333@HHS_998', '7859000@FGL3', '44532009@LLLKH_9', '225@DDMDM'],
 ['78271@WQE', '8003013@UTTY7']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution even I don't understand it too much :)

Comment: You're welcome. `groupby` will form the nested lists (the groups) and the check will filter out the final list. Try to remove `if check` form the listcomp to see the result ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` ([link to Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GrKL7t/1)):

```py
import re

data = """ABCD1
2040805025@HHS_2332
801111@PPOD_1
225@DDMDM
DEFA1
23333@HHS_998
7859000@FGL3
44532009@LLLKH_9
225@DDMDM
FGGH5
78271@WQE
8003013@UTTY7"""

out = [
    group.splitlines()
    for group in re.findall(r"^.{5}$\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^.{5}$|\Z)", data, flags=re.S | re.M)
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ["2040805025@HHS_2332", "801111@PPOD_1", "225@DDMDM"],
    ["23333@HHS_998", "7859000@FGL3", "44532009@LLLKH_9", "225@DDMDM"],
    ["78271@WQE", "8003013@UTTY7"],
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What your regex does is match all except 5 characters string?